# Taking JSON list of objects and putting them into a python list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, object

I'm new to working with JSON in Python. I have a program where I generate 10 characters (objects) that have several properties. I'm write these to a file using the Python JSON library:

```
def saveCharsToFile(gameChars):
# Using a WITH operator for easy readability. creating and opening a file
# in write mode
with open("characterFile.json", "w") as write_file:
    # using the json.dump function to take the objects in the gameChars
    # list and serialise it into JSON
    json.dump([x.__dict__ for x in gameChars], write_file)
    # Tells the User that the file has been written

print("File 'characterFile.json' has been written to...")
```

Here is an example of one of the types of classes that generate a character:

```
# A subclass for creating a Wizard character, inherits the Character class
# and adds the power, sAttackPwr, and speed properties
class wizard(character):
    def __init__(self, CharPower, CharSAttackPwr, CharSpeed):
        # Getting the properties from the inheritted character Base Class
        character.__init__(self, "W", 100)
        self.power = CharPower
        self.sAttackPwr = CharSAttackPwr
        self.speed = CharSpeed


# Base Class for creating an RPG character
class character:
    # __init__ method, creates the name, type, health properties
    def __init__(self, charType, charHealth):
        self.name = rndName()
        self.type = charType
        self.health = charHealth
```

Here is the contents of a file saved using the saveCharsToFile:

```
[{"name": "ing low fu ", "type": "B", "health": 100, "power": 60, "sAttackPwr": 10, "speed": 60}, {"name": "en ar da ", "type": "W", "health": 100, "power": 50, "sAttackPwr": 70, "speed": 30}, {"name": "ar fu fu ", "type": "B", "health": 100, "power": 70, "sAttackPwr": 20, "speed": 50}, {"name": "da low en ", "type": "W", "health": 100, "power": 50, "sAttackPwr": 70, "speed": 30}, {"name": "da fu cha ", "type": "D", "health": 100, "power": 90, "sAttackPwr": 40, "speed": 50}, {"name": "da ing el ", "type": "W", "health": 100, "power": 50, "sAttackPwr": 70, "speed": 30}, {"name": "cha kar low ", "type": "D", "health": 100, "power": 90, "sAttackPwr": 40, "speed": 50}, {"name": "ar da el ", "type": "D", "health": 100, "power": 90, "sAttackPwr": 40, "speed": 50}, {"name": "da da ant ", "type": "B", "health": 100, "power": 60, "sAttackPwr": 10, "speed": 60}, {"name": "el ing kar ", "type": "B", "health": 100, "power": 70, "sAttackPwr": 20, "speed": 50}]
```

I'd like to be able to read this back into the program, as a list, preferably instantiating them as objects with the values for the character properties in that list above.

This is the current way I'm reading the file back into the program:

```
def openCharsToFile(gameChars):
    with open("characterFile.json") as read_file:
        y = json.load(read_file)
        for x in y:
            gameChars.insert[x, y]

        for z in gameChars:
            print(z.getStats())
```

But when I run this program, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "rpgProblemSolving.py", line 342, in <module>
        main()
    File "rpgProblemSolving.py",  line 338, in main
        openCharsToFile(gameChars)
    File "rpgProblemSolving.py", line 305, in openCharsToFile
        gameChars.insert[x, y]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

If anyone has some suggestions, It would be most appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you wanted to just add your character to existing characters, so use append instead. Your error was that you had `[x, y]` instead of `(x, y)`, but even if we fix that that makes no sense since first argument (`x`) of insert is index of list (`gameChars`) where your `y` will be inserted, which makes no sense since `x` is your character and `y` is your dict.

Also part where you print your characters `print(z.getStats())` won't work since `gameChars` contains only characters in form of dictionaries that of course doesn't have such method as `getStats()`.

```
def openCharsToFile(gameChars):
    with open("characterFile.json") as read_file:
        y = json.load(read_file)
        for x in y:
            gameChars.append(x)

        for z in gameChars:
            print(z.getStats())
```